# How do I present multiple UIAlertController one after another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, for-in-loop

Inside of a forin loop, I need to present an UIAlertController and wait for user confirmation before presenting the next one. I presented them inside a forin loop, but only the first one appears(after confirmation, the others don't show up).Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you putting in for loop? As you told you have to wait for user confirmation so create a new alert on button action of Alertcontroller,

Comment: The problem is that each alert performs a task when the user confirms(UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet with multiple options). I'm trying to perform a task on multiple objects with different options that a user selects.

Comment: Is this really the best user experience? As you say in a comment below, what if you have 100 objects? Are you really going to make the user confirm 100 separate alerts? That would be bad.

Comment: @rmaddy It's just an example of the worst case that usually never happens. What I'm trying to do is for each object to perform an action depending on which option was selected in the UIAlertController with action sheet style. I select the objects in a uitableview and they get put into an array. Is there a better a way to loop through the array and give the user multiple choice selection for each object?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the UIAlertController delegate when a button is pressed you show the next alert.

Make a global alert index:

```
NSUInteger alertIndex = 0;
```

Make a global NSArray with your alert details in a NSDictionary eg:

```
self.alerts = @[@{@"title":@"Alert", @"message":@"Message 1"}, @{@"title":@"Alert", @"message":@"Message 2"}];
```

Call your first alert with an index, eg:

```
...title:self.alerts[alertIndex][@"title"]...
```

and

```
...message:self.alerts[alertIndex][@"message"]...
```

In your alert controller delegate's didClickButtonAtIndex:

```
alertIndex++;
// call your next alert here, explained above.
```

Comment: What happens if I have 100 objects? I'm using UIAlertControllerSytleActionSheet for my UIAlertController and each object could show different options for the user to select.

Comment: Do not make anything a global. Perhaps you mean instance variable or property?

Comment: That is possible, will be just be more complex and you need to handle each one differently. I've never seen something like this before, doubt Apple would approve.. why not make 5 view controllers with 20 segmented buttons or something in that line? Yes @rmaddy you can edit if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

I need to do something similar to display hints to users throughout my app.
Just managed to cobble this together and it works quite well and is easy to adapt and add to ...

```
        /////
        // Alert Properties in @interface
        ////
        @property NSOperationQueue *queue;
        @property NSMutableArray* operationArray;
        @property int operationCounter;
        @property int operationTotal;
        /////
        // Alert Properties End
        ////




        /////////
        // Multi Alert Code Start
        ////////


        - (void) alertCodeWithTitleString: (NSString*) titlestring AndMessageString:(NSString*)messagestring {
        NSOperation *tempoperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^(void) {



            NSString* tutTitleString = titlestring;
            NSString* tutMessageString = messagestring;




            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                            alertControllerWithTitle:tutTitleString
                                            message:tutMessageString
                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


                        UIAlertAction* dontshow = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Don't Show This Again"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {



                                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                        self.operationCounter++;

                                        [self alertOperationCallMethod2];


                                }];
                                UIAlertAction* done = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Close"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {

                                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                    self.operationCounter++;

                                    [self alertOperationCallMethod2];

                                }];

                        [alert addAction:done];
                        [alert addAction:dontshow];

                        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                });

            } ];


        self.operationTotal++;
        [self.operationArray addObject:tempoperation];

        }

        -(void) alertOperationCallMethod1 {

        self.operationCounter = 0;
        self.operationTotal = 0;


        self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        self.operationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


            [self alertCodeWithTitleString:@"Title1" AndMessageString:@"Message1"];

            [self alertCodeWithTitleString:@"Title2" AndMessageString:@"Message2"];

            [self alertCodeWithTitleString:@"Title3" AndMessageString:@"Message3"];

            //  Just keep adding method calls here to add alerts

            [self alertOperationCallMethod2];




        }
        -(void) alertOperationCallMethod2 {

        if (self.operationCounter<self.operationTotal) {

        [self.queue addOperation:self.operationArray[self.operationCounter]];

        }

        }

        -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
           [super viewWillAppear:animated];
           //something here

        [self alertOperationCallMethod1];

           }
        /////////
        // Multi Alert Code End
        ////////

        ----
```

All you need to do is add another method call in alertOperationCallMethod1

Multiple versions of alertCodeWith..... method should allow you to customise your alerts to suit.

Hope this helps someone : )

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/arkdan/ARKExtensions#alertcontroller) UIViewController extension does what you want:

> **The alerts queue up, fifo.** I.e. latter alers wait and don't show until
>   user respond to former alerts.